# Migrating Spring 3.x to Spring 4.x: Cause BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring

The below code is a piece of code and not complete code:

SystemConfigDAO.java

```
package com.model.dao.systemconfig;
@Component( "syncSystemConfigDAO" )
@DependsOn({"dao.DAOFramework"})
public class SystemConfigDAO {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SystemConfigDAO.class);
  /**
  * Default connection to database
  */
   public SystemConfigDAO() {
     this(DAOFramework.getInstance());
   }

}
```

SystemConfigManager.java

```
package com.manager.systemconfig;
@Component
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "com.model.dao.systemconfig" )
@Scope("singleton")
@DependsOn({"dao.DAOFramework"})

public class SystemConfigManager {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SystemConfigManager.class);

@Autowired
SystemConfigDAO systemConfigDAO;

 public void saveValue(String key, Long tenant, Long user, ConfigValue value){
  if (value == null) {
    systemConfigDAO.removeValue(key, tenant, user);
  } else {
    systemConfigDAO.saveValue(key, tenant, user, value.getValue(), value.getType(), value.getLastModified());
  }
 }
}
```

DAOFramework.java

```
package com.dal;
public class DAOFramework {

private static volatile ApplicationContext context;
/**
 * Declare Spring id for default framework instance
 */
public static final String FRAMEWORK_BEAN_NAME="dao.DAOFramework";

@Autowired(required = true)
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    context = applicationContext;
}
public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}
AtomicReference<Morphia> _morphia = new AtomicReference<Morphia>();

/**
 *
 * @return default instance of DAO framework
 */
public static DAOFramework getInstance(){
    return (DAOFramework) getApplicationContext().getBean(FRAMEWORK_BEAN_NAME);
}

public static  Object getBean(String beanName){
    return  getApplicationContext().getBean(beanName);
}

public void setConnection(MongoClient mongo){
    _connection.compareAndSet(null, mongo);
}

AtomicReference<MongoClient> _connection = new AtomicReference<MongoClient>();
private String _DBName;

/**
 * Connection to MongoDB shared per multiple threads. Per mongo's doc:
 * "The Mongo object instance actually represents a pool of connections
 * to the database; you will only need one object of class Mongo even with multiple threads."
 * @return single instance of Mongo
 */
public MongoClient getConnection(){
    return _connection.get();
}

/**
 * Deprecating in favor of mongo3 MongoDatabase
 * @return default pre-configured database
 */
@Deprecated 
public DB getDB(){
    return getConnection().getDB(getDBName());
}

public MongoDatabase getDatabase()
{
    return getConnection().getDatabase(getDBName());
}
/**
 *
 * @return name of default database used by entire project
 */
public String getDBName() {
    return _DBName;
}

public void setDBName(String dBName) {
    this._DBName = dBName;
}
List<String> _entityPackages;

/**
 * @return list of packages to locate entities for Morphia
 */
public List<String> getEntityPackages() {
    return _entityPackages;
}

/**
 * @param entityPackages new list of entities
 */
public void setEntityPackages(List<String> entityPackages) {
    this._entityPackages = entityPackages;
}

/**
 * Get single instance of Morphia. It is thread-safe per google comment (http://groups.google.com/group/morphia/browse_thread/thread/bc981e664b9f04d5)
 * @return application-wide single instance of Morphia
 */
public Morphia getMorphia() {
    if( _morphia.get() == null ){//no morphia initialized yet
        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
        //first time need assign entities mappings
        for(String pack : getEntityPackages()){//iterate all packages to locate entities
            for(Class<?> c : EntityDiscover.getClassesInPackage(pack, ".+Entity$")){
                morphia.map(c);
            }
        }
        //assign only thread-safe way
        _morphia.compareAndSet(null, morphia);
    }
    /**/
    return _morphia.get();
}

/**
 * Create Morphia-like DAO class instance with specified entity
 * @param entity type will be used for serialize/deserialize operations
 * @return instance that can be used for morphia manipulation with entity. This instance is shared
 * between multiple threads.
 */
public DAOExtension createDAO(Class entity){
    return DAOExtension.getInstance(entity, this);
}
```

}

spring.xml

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.model.*"/>
<bean id="dao.daoFramework.entityPackages" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>com.model.entity</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<import resource="spring-db.xml"/>
```

spring-db.xml

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.dal.*" />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.model.dao."/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.manager."></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config />
<bean id="dao.DAOFramework" class="com.dal.DAOFramework">
        <property name="connection" ref="mongoClient"/>
        <property name="DBName" value="${mongo-db}"/>
        <property name="entityPackages">
            <ref bean="dao.daoFramework.entityPackages" />
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="mongoClient" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject"><ref local="mongoFactory"/></property>
    <property name="targetMethod"><value>getMongoClient</value></property>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoFactory" class="com.stratasync.dal.MongoFactory">
    <property name="connectionsPerHost" value="${mongo-connections}"></property>
    <property name="autoConnectRetry" value="${mongo-autoConnectRetry}"></property>
    <property name="socketKeepAlive" value="true"></property>
    <property name="threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier" value="${mongo-connectionsBacklog}"></property>
            <property name="mongoHosts">
                    <list>
                            <bean class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
                                    <constructor-arg value="${mongo-host1}"></constructor-arg>
                            </bean>
                            <bean class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
                                    <constructor-arg value="${mongo-host2}"></constructor-arg>
                            </bean>
                            <bean class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
                                    <constructor-arg value="${mongo-host3}"></constructor-arg>
                            </bean>
                    </list>
     </property>
     <property name="mongoCredentials">
            <list>
                <ref bean="mongoCredentialID"/>
            </list>
    </property>
    <property name="writeConcern">
        <bean id="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">  
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Caused by:

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'systemConfigManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO com.manager.systemconfig.SystemConfigManager.systemConfigDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'syncSystemConfigDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/Universe/WEB-INF/lib/data-access-5.1.0.0.jar!/com/model/dao/systemconfig/SystemConfigDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at com.stratasync.dal.DAOFramework.getBean(DAOFramework.java:45)
    at com.beans.ServiceAndManagerBeansCollection.getSystemConfigManager(ServiceAndManagerBeansCollection.java:253)
    at com.distconf.DistributedConfig.<init>(DistributedConfig.java:39)
    at com.distconf.DistributedConfig.getInstance(DistributedConfig.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 84 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO com.manager.systemconfig.SystemConfigManager.systemConfigDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'syncSystemConfigDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/Universe/WEB-INF/lib/data-access-5.1.0.0.jar!/com/model/dao/systemconfig/SystemConfigDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 105 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'syncSystemConfigDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/Universe/WEB-INF/lib/data-access-5.1.0.0.jar!/com/model/dao/systemconfig/SystemConfigDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 107 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dal.DAOFramework.getMorphia(DAOFramework.java:113)
at com.dal.DAOExtension.<init>(DAOExtension.java:111)
at com.dal.DAOExtension.createInstance(DAOExtension.java:145)
at com.dal.DAOExtension.getInstance(DAOExtension.java:135)
at com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO.<init>(SystemConfigDAO.java:65)
at com.model.dao.systemconfig.SystemConfigDAO.<init>(SystemConfigDAO.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
... 120 more
```

Related cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dao.DAOFramework' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-db.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1362)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:726)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:523)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:357)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedSet(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:158)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:110)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
... 62 more
```

Tried various suggestion available online, added `@ComponentScan` basePackage in SystemCongiManager.java and added `component-scan` in `spring-db.xml` but none of them worked. I also tried to keep with both the options but still same error. Please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: There is a Problem in your Definition of DAOFramework. Where are the setter of the Parameter you defined in xml

Comment: @Jens Are you taking about mongoClient?If yes, i have added it.

Comment: I am talking about DBname,Connection and entityPackages. I can not see it in your code

Comment: @Jens There are setters available for all in DAOFramework, I didn't attached complete piece of code earlier but now i have.

Comment: Cna you remove one property after the other and check if the error is gone, to see which Parameter causes the Problem?

Comment: @Jens entityPackages  at DAOFramework, getEntityPackages() is throwing NullPointerException                   for(String pack : getEntityPackages()){
                for(Class<?> c : EntityDiscover.getClassesInPackage(pack, ".+Entity$")){
                    morphia.map(c);
                }

Comment: If you remove the property `entitypackages` from the xmlfile?

Comment: @Jens I have removed entitypackages form xml file but still the same trace with same set of exceptions.

Comment: But you wrote you get a NPE?!

Comment: Yes, I looked at the trace Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dal.DAOFramework.getMorphia(DAOFramework.java:113)
at com.dal.DAOExtension.<init>(DAOExtension.java:111) and figured out that its throwing NPE. You can see ful trace above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122006/discussion-between-harleen-and-jens).